# merge separate queries into one query

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa

i have the following query using boolQueryBuilder which check if status1 or status2 AND the time is less than currentTime is matchs :

```
 public BoolQueryBuilder createSearchQuery(Long currentTime) {
        // Build and operator
        final BoolQueryBuilder firstAndOperator = createAndOperator(currentTime, "status1");

        // Build AND operator 
        final BoolQueryBuilder secondAndOperator = createAndOperator(currentTime, "status2);

        // Build OR
        return createOrOperator(firstAndOperator, secondAndOperator);
    }

    private BoolQueryBuilder createOrOperator(BoolQueryBuilder firstAndOperator, BoolQueryBuilder secondAndOperator) {
        return new BoolQueryBuilder()
            .should(firstAndOperator)
            .should(secondAndOperator);
    }

    private BoolQueryBuilder createAndOperator(Long currentDate, Status status) {
        return QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(STATUS, status))
            .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(TIME).lte(currentDate));
    }
```

how to merge them using multiMatchQuery?

this is my try but it does not work

```
 public BoolQueryBuilder createSearchQuery(Long currentTime) {
        return new BoolQueryBuilder()
            .should(QueryBuilders
                .multiMatchQuery("status1" + " " + "status2", STATUS)
                .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX)
                .operator(Operator.OR))
            .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(TIME)
                .lte(currentTime));
    }
```

Comment: it's not clear what you need to merge...

Comment: Its about converting syntax

Comment: Using multiquery

Comment: Yes, but it is not clear what query you want to merge with what other query? And how they should be merged.... maybe write the query you'd expect to have in the DSL language so it will be more clear

Comment: So what i want is, to simplify that shoud and must operations to one with multiyquery

Comment: Ok, but can you explain what "does not work" mean? Do you get a syntax error or you don't get the results you expect? If the latter, what do you get vs what do you expect to get instead?

Comment: I am not getting the expectation result i need to get a hint if the status1 or status2 AND Time less than today are true

Comment: Please see the answer I've provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `multi_match` query is wrong and you should use `filter` instead of `must` as well. So it should be like this instead:

```
public BoolQueryBuilder createSearchQuery(Long currentTime) {
    return new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .should(QueryBuilders
            .multiMatchQuery(STATUS, "status1", "status2")
            .operator(Operator.OR))
        .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(TIME)
            .lte(currentTime));
```

But I wouldn't use `multi_match` for that purpose, instead I would leverage two `term` filters:

```
public BoolQueryBuilder createSearchQuery(Long currentTime) {
    return new BoolQueryBuilder()
        .minimumShouldMatch(1)
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status1", STATUS))
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status2", STATUS))
        .filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(TIME)
            .lte(currentTime));
```

Comment: i get SearchHits{totalHits=0, totalHitsRelation=EQUAL_TO, maxScore=NaN, scrollId='null', searchHits={0 elements}, aggregations=null}

Comment: With which query? the first or the second one?

Comment: both of them :/

Comment: I've updated my second query, can you try it out? If it doesn't work, can you share your index mapping please?

Comment: it works with matchQuery instaed of termQuery

Comment: Ok, that's because you have text field instead of keyword ones. That's fine. Glad we figured it out.

Comment: in this case, it does not work with multiMathquery right?

Comment: can you share your index mapping please?